# Integrating Docusign Customers to my certified app

Tags: docusignapi

Thanks for the answer to my previous question Ergin... I'm going to follow up with one more question, because I'm SURE that I'm not understanding correctly.... I can't believe it is so hard.

My company enboarder has created a workflow engine.   We have gone through certification with Docusign and have **our** integrator key.

One of our joint customers "Acme Corp" is an existing Docusign customer.

They want to link their Docusign account to Enboarder so that our app can trigger their docusign workflows.

Am I understanding it correctly that they need to go through the entire certification process even as an end-user customer?
thx in advance
Brent

Answer (score 1):

Your customer will not need to go through any certification process to use your solution.

Now that your integration is certified your customer would just need to supply credentials (Email/Password/AccountId) for their existing DocuSign account so that your code would use those supplied credentials (along with your certified IK) to authenticate to DS.

A pattern some solutions use is to have a user interface in your system where the customer can enter the email address and password of their existing DS account. You would use those credentials to call the [`Login`](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Login.htm?Highlight=login_information) API method to get back a list of the accounts associated with that user. If the user has more than one account (personal, work, etc.) then your system should present them with the option to pick from a list of accounts. Once they've selected the account they want to use with your integration you should store the selected **accountId**, **userId** and **apiPassword** (returned by [`Login`](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Login.htm?Highlight=login_information) API call) in your system configuration data. Your **integratorKey** along with that stored **userId**, **accountId**, and **apiPassword** would be used in your solution to authenticate to DS.

Hope this helps, it is a lot of moving parts, but it can be done! Let me know if you want any further clarification. We have a solution in production that is successfully doing what I've described here.

Comment: Thanks Steve,  thats. great.